# fullCalendar adding a class to events

Tags: fullcalendar

I am trying to select events on fullcalendar, based on user selection.

Example: if user selects class A, then all classes with the same ID should turn green (using applied className).

I am having trouble applying classes to the other events that I can successfully select by ID. I guess my issue is combining the event objects with jQuery objects.

sample code:

```
eventClick: function(event) {
  $(this).addClass("reg_selected");  //this works fine on selected event
  var selectedID = event.id
  alert(selectedID);                 //get event.ID, and use it to find similar ones.
  var similarEvents = $("#calendar").fullCalendar('clientEvents',selectedID).addClass("reg_selected");
```

the error I get is:

```
  addClass is not a function
```

I also tried this method of looping, and got the same error:

```
for (var i = 0; similarEvents.length > i ; i++){
    alert(similarEvents[i].title);
    similarEvents[i].className("reg_selected");
}
```

the alert() worked, but the className() generated the same error as above

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[clientEvents](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/clientEvents/) returns an array of matching objects. You need to iterate through the array (in your case similarEvents) and call addClass for each item

Update:
There is also issues using an id to update multiple events, using a filter function instead is a better way to go.

```
eventClick: function(event) {
    var similarEvents = $("#calendar").fullCalendar('clientEvents', function(e) { return e.test === event.test });

    for (var i = 0; similarEvents.length > i ; i++){
            similarEvents[i].className = 'reg_selected';
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('updateEvent', similarEvents[i]);
        }
},
```

See [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mEwsK/10/)

Comment: thanks muchly - i just updated the question with some code i have previously tried, getting the same error. your help is appreciated!

Comment: className is a property not an method. Try `similarEvents[i].className = "reg_selected";`

Comment: no, `similarEvents[i].className = "reg_selected";` didnt seem to work. no error - but it didnt work.

Comment: It seems that it is actually changing the event, but you need to call `$('#mycalendar').fullCalendar('updateEvent', similarEvents[i]);` in order to update the calendar. The problem with this is that because the id is the same it's not updating properly. I don't have time to investigate properly but I think if you can use some other filter rather than having the id the same for different events you should be able to get it working

Comment: See updated code, should be able to achieve what you want from this example

Answer (score 9):

This answer for a very similar situation, but when event classes are selected with **round-trip to the event source** for possible persistence in the db or checks.

Class name can be specified in the event object in the source as follows (start and end given for the context only):

```
[{
  ...
  "className": "selected-event",
  "start": '2017-05-01T08:30:00.0',
  "ends": '2017-05-01T09:00:00.0',
  ...
}, ...]
```

The idea is that user clicks the event; ajax call to select events goes to backend; onsuccess, frontend javascript does`$calendar.fullCalendar('rerenderEvents');` and receives the event source with events' classes. The immediate child of `.fc-event-container` gets the specified class, in the example above - `selected-event`.

As a result, the selection can be persisted on the backend.

Answer (score 3):

For fullcalendar add event class, id and title see this.

```
if($('#eventTitle').val() == "Avilable") {
   eventClass = "avilable";
}else {
   eventClass = "unavilable";
}

$myCalendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent', {
  id:response,
  title: title.val(),
  start: start.val(),
  end: end.val(),
  allDay: true,
  className: eventClass,
  color: color
  }, true
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get it working with the following code:

```
eventRender: function (eventObj, $el) {
    $el.addClass(eventObj.ClassName);
},
```

eventObj.ClassName = `"calendar-priority-warning"`